# heartbeat: find out machine's status within a cluster?

Tags: linux, failover, high-availability, heartbeat

I'm trying to do some heartbeat debugging.

Is there a simple way to ask a machine whether it thinks it's part of a cluster, and whether it's the master or the slave?

I've tried

```
$ heartbeat -s
```

But it only seems to print a very basic status - running with process ID, or not running.

Comment: Previously (i.e. v < 2.1.4) `crm_mon` was part of the heartbeat package and would do this. If you have Pacemaker installed, `crm_mon -n` should list each node in the cluster (and its current status) as well as identifying the master node.

Comment: master and slave? There is normally one primary node and the other nodes (for each resource group). Do you run just one resource group in your cluster?

Answer (score 7):

Are you using V1 or V2 syntax?

With V1 there is `cl_status rscstatus` which will return the Cluster`s Idea of resource distribution (none, local, all).

- none: All resource groups are running on a different node
- local: All resource groups that belong to this node run on this node
- all: All resource groups run on this node

There are some other useful options for cl_status - just call it on the command line...

Also try `/etc/init.d/heartbeat status`

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @cyberx86, `crm_mon` shows the cluster status. If you want to use a graphical X11 application, `hb_gui` offers you that. `hb_gui` allows you to also control your cluster.

[image: hbgui screenshot]