# How to check which node is the master with heartbeat?

Tags: heartbeat, linux-ha, heartbeat1

I need to know which machine is the current active node in an active(1)-passive(n) cluster.

Reading the docs I could come up with

```
cl_status rscstatus <node name>
```

which returns various values that are not that precise (all, transition, foreign, none, local). Is there any definite way to know which one is the master node?

Comment: Heartbeat 1 or heartbeat 2?

Comment: Heartbeat 3.0.5

Comment: The question is - do you use `haresources` (v1 - ASCII) or v2-XML for your configuration?

Comment: That would be `haresources` v1

Comment: possible duplicate of [heartbeat: find out machine's status within a cluster?](http://serverfault.com/questions/333853/heartbeat-find-out-machines-status-within-a-cluster)